# How to use Free Templates having Bootstrap ,CSS, Jquery.. with ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, view

I need to use a template for my webapplication, I have the template code in html, but don't know how to fit it in my MVC4 architecture. `https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html`

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully used Template after putting some effort to understand it.

I have created a _layout view to separate the navigation layout from the template index.html and copied all references js/css files in script folder and change there reference path in layout as well.

it is very easy.

However I found some of jquery functions are not working in template like .datepicker, .model and .valid or .validation. insted of these the template using parsely validation methods, daterangepicker js  and bootstrap for model popup.

It is not always easy to use templates but if you understand it well, it will reduce your UI efforts in project development.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});
</script>
```